# Phrase concept of self-knowledge?

Tags: phrasing

I don't know how to express this.
I want to say that the ugliness of adolescence is hidden BUT not for adolescents themselves.
Is this sentence correct? is there a better phrasing?
"the ugliness of this stage is obscured but not to adolescents themselves"

Thank you

Comment: Anthropologists call such external perspectives "*etic*", and the corresponding internal perspectives "*emic*". A group may have a particular religious practice, and the "*emic*" belief is they do it to please their gods, but a Western scientist may have the "*etic*" perspective that the practice arose for food-sanitation or preservation reasons (e.g. kosher practices in ancient Judea).  Fair warning: I may have mixed up which one was *emic* and which *etic*.

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match the text of your question.  The title is very broad but I think it is also possible to answer your real question in a way that does not satisfy the title at all.  For example, it might be possible to use a Mystery Cult metaphor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_mysteries), likening adolescents to initiates in a misery cult, which would satisfy your real question while failing according to your title.

Comment: @itsbruce +1 for "adolescents in a *misery* cult" :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you did great.  Here:

> The ugliness of adolescence is hidden - but not from adolescents
>   themselves.

Note that "not not from _ _ _ themselves" is a somewhat standard form.  So, you're using that.  Enjoy!

Comment: There are definitely more expressive ways to say it, though not all would be appropriate, depending on the context.

Comment: Its almost an ELL question. The OP just wants to know if that sounds good - it does with a tweak. As I mention the last half is a "standard form".  Regarding writing it again kratively, anyone here could do so ten times but I only write kratively for money  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a clinical term, but it might be apt to use [hypergnosis](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hypergnosis) in a loose sense to describe the heightened state of self-awareness that characterises adolescence.